# write a procedure to get multiple records

Tags: mysql

I am writing a procedure, I want to get multiple records, Below is my query, any help please

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `callHolidays`()
BEGIN
SET @emp = (SELECT id,name from default_holidays WHERE year = '2022');
SET @empCount = (SELECT count(id) as count from default_holidays WHERE year = '2022');
IF @empCount > 0 THEN
 WHILE condition

  INSERT INTO 
  holidays(id,company_id,name,date,all_years,year)values(values);

 END WHILE
END
```

Comment: *I want to get multiple records* Iimagine that you got them. What you'd do with? send to output stream like they're selected by common SELECT query? or something else?

Comment: Hi @Akina, After getting multiple records, I want to write insert query based on records using loop......Please check my updated query

Comment: Every if must have an endif. And where is company_id, and all_years coming from?

Comment: For clarity add sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: Hi @ Salmon, Please look into my mysql fiddle , Those results, I want to get

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e05807/3

Comment: (1) `SET @emp =` - does not guarantee that the subquery returns only one row. Add LIMIT 1 to the subquery. And use `SELECT INTO` instead of `SET`. (2) `SET @empCount =` is excess - you may use your subquery in `IF` directly. (3) `WHILE condition` - what is `condition`? (4) `INSERT INTO .. values(values);` - what is `values` in the parenthesis?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e52fc86c67efa283dc36a8de7046ef72 PS. Static `year` column seems to be excess. Remove it and use ```WHERE YEAR(`date`) = 2022``` or make it generated.

Comment: @Akina, Here insert into values is,      I am inserting those same holidays list in my local DB, I want to get the holidays list from my main Database and want to insert those data in sub database, Both main & sub DB columns are same i.e id, name, year, date

Comment: I see [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please describe complete task which you try to solve.

Comment: @Akina, I have a list of holidays list in my main database with table name as default_holidays, I want to insert those holidays list in my sub database, and I want to run those at yearly once, So I want to write a procedure and then, I want to call a event and in event, I will keep it to execute once in a year. 
For that I want to get the holidays list ffrom Main database and want to insert them in sub database

Comment: Well. The table and sample data are already provided. Now provide: CREATE TABLE for a table in your sub-database which the holidays must be copied into, desired final table data state after successful copying.

Comment: In Sub DB, I am having already the table, 
I just want to insert the holidays data for the year 2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you may not be aware of INSERT..SELECT https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Your entire code could be replaced by

```
INSERT INTO  holidays
 (id,
 #company_id,
 name,
 #date, all_years,
 year)
 select id,name,year
 from default_holidays
 where year = '2022';
```

And I would paramterise the year test so you don't have to change it every year.